# Php Reusable code, with less line Or function to make it reusable code

Tags: php, function

Want to make below code reusable with less line instead of repeating it.Ex put the code in some function etc. So code will look clean and optimize.

```
 if($pos_Year) {
        preg_match('/^([=<>!]+)([0-9]+)$/', $pos_Year, $tokens);
        $operator = $tokens[1];
        $operand  = $tokens[2];
        $ck_year = create_function('$value', '
        $operand = '.$operand.';
        switch("'.$operator.'") {
            case "==": return ($value==$operand);
            case "!=": return ($value!=$operand);
            case "<":  return ($value<$operand);
            case "<=": return ($value==$operand);
            case ">":  return ($value>$operand);
            case ">=": return ($value>=$operand);
            default:   throw new Exception("invalid operator");
        }');
    }

    if($pos_Month) {
        preg_match('/^([=<>!]+)([0-9]+)$/', $pos_Month, $tokens);
        $operator = $tokens[1];
        $operand  = $tokens[2];
        $ck_month = create_function('$value', '
        $operand = '.$operand.';
        switch("'.$operator.'") {
            case "==": return ($value==$operand);
            case "!=": return ($value!=$operand);
            case "<":  return ($value<$operand);
            case "<=": return ($value==$operand);
            case ">":  return ($value>$operand);
            case ">=": return ($value>=$operand);
            default:   throw new Exception("invalid operator");
        }');
    }
$ck_year(2014);
$ck_month(6);
```

Comment: so....what exactly is your question?

Comment: i Dont want to repeat code, Just call a function in if condition.

Comment: So don't. Again, what is the question?

Comment: example  reusable_code(){ ...Contains the Code } if($pos_Year) {
       reusable_code();
    }   if($pos_Month) {
       reusable_code();
    }

Comment: I understand what you want to do, i just don't understand what is your difficulty...what is holding you back?

Comment: I Cant figure it out how to do it

Answer (score 0):

The "rules" to remove duplicate, or nearly duplicate code are simple:
1) find similar code, with small or no differences
2) encapsulate the code as a function or method
3) replace differences or potential differences with arguments passed into the function / method.

I'm lacking context, particularly for the "$value" and "$tokens" variables, but in your case, the code is very similar, with just one parameter (maybe 2 or 3 if the 2 mentioned variables also change). You don't even need the "if" condition in the function - it should go outside (if at all):

```
function check_value($theValue)
{
    preg_match('/^([=<>!]+)([0-9]+)$/', $theValue, $tokens);
    $operator = $tokens[1];
    $operand  = $tokens[2];
    $ck_month = create_function('$value', '
    $operand = '.$operand.';
    switch("'.$operator.'") {
        case "==": return ($value==$operand);
        case "!=": return ($value!=$operand);
        case "<":  return ($value<$operand);
        case "<=": return ($value==$operand);
        case ">":  return ($value>$operand);
        case ">=": return ($value>=$operand);
        default:   throw new Exception("invalid operator");
    }');
}

$ck_value(2014);
$ck_value(6);
```

Comment: form the above code check_value function has a sub function  $ck_month How to call that function.